# Applying textures correctly to extruded elliptical objects in three.js

Tags: three.js, bounding-box, texturing, uv-mapping

For a while now I've been having difficulty correctly applying textures to three.js custom objects. Specifically extruded elliptical objects. I have looked around and from what I can see I need to generate the objects UV mapping by using it's bounding box. However, I am unsure exactly how to do this and I can't seem to find any detailed explanation on how this works. Can anyone help explain this process to me in detail?

Thanks,
zaidi92